# Как создать Адаптивный дизайн для Разрешений экранов с одной Длиной но разной Шириной?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

СУТЬ: сделать адаптивный дизайн для разрешений экранов: 1280x1024 / 1280x800 / 1280x768 / 1280x720 / 1280x600.
На данный момент, реализовано через media queries так: @media(max-width:1280px) но таким способом можно сделать адаптивный дизайн только для одного из разрешений выше, как сделать для всех разрешений ?

Comment: Это не отвечает на мой вопрос

Comment: А я и не просил просто комментарий.

Comment: жаль вас, если вы считаете своим долгом, увидев вопрос, и не желая ответить на него, все равно прокомментировать абсолютно без никакого смысла, знаешь ответ, ответь, не знаешь, пройди мимо.

Comment: Простой пример, один участник сервиса toster уже ответил на мой вопрос, ответил коротко и лаконично, он видел что я ошибся, называя ширину экрана длиной, а высоту шириной, но он не стал оставлять глупый, бессмысленный коммент, а предоставил в точности что я хотел, я уверен, что если бы он не знал ответа на данный вопрос, то просто проигнорил бы его, и это объективно правильный подход, удачи вам в вашей нелегкой жизни.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, если кому-либо это поможет, то вот ответ:

```
@media (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:1024px) { ... }

@media (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:800px) { ... }

@media (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:720px) { ... }
```

Comment: Код полагается форматировать. И не стоит комментарии принимать в штыки.

Answer (score 0):

(max-width:1280px and min-width:1024px) и так далее (max-width:1024px and min-width:800px)
так не пробовали?

Comment: К сожалению данный метод не работает

Comment: у вас max-width(1280px) находится в файле выше чем max-width(1024px)